# Separate main class and other functions within main class into separate class files

Tags: java, class

I have just one 'mainclass' class, within the class have written other functions, since the code increasing now it's hard do any changes for me. So I want keep one mainClass separate and rest of the functions in different classes separate and call them in the mainClass, so that any changes/updates, I can only change the sub classes which will reflect in the mainClass. Since I newbie! please show me how to split into sub class and called those sub class in main Class.

```
public class mainClass extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frmScms;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JPanel panel3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mainClass window = new mainClass();
                    window.frmScms.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public mainClass() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frmScms = new JFrame();
        frmScms.setTitle("SCMS");
        frmScms.setBounds(100, 100, 1080, 684);
        frmScms.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frmScms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmScms.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frmScms.setResizable(true);

        //Set the frame icon to an image loaded from a file.
        frmScms.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("images/company-logo.gif").getImage());

        //creating pages
        createPageScreen1();
        createPageScreen2();
        createPageScreen3();

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(2, 20, 1900, 1080);

        //tool tip for screen-1 to 6
        String tooltip1 = "Screen-1";
        String tooltip2 = "Screen-2";
        String tooltip3 = "Screen-3";


        // Create a tabbed pane
        tabbedPane.addTab("Screen-1", null, panel1, tooltip1);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Screen-2", null, panel2, tooltip2);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Screen-3", null, panel3, tooltip3);
        frmScms.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        //warning message before close using X 
        frmScms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frmScms.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to close the application?", "Please Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

    //function for panel - page - 1
    public void createPageScreen1() {
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );


        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/Front1.png");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(image, JLabel.CENTER);
        label2.setBounds( 10, 55, 1600, 900 );
        panel1.add(label2);
    }

    //function for panel - page - 2
    public void createPageScreen2() {
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout( null );

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel( "LOG:" );
        label1.setBounds( 10, 15, 150, 20 );
        panel2.add( label1 );

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel( "Well 1 PMW Pressure Sensor - Tag xx123" );
        label2.setBounds( 10, 45, 300, 20 );
        panel2.add( label2 );
    }

    //function for panel - page - 3
    public void createPageScreen3() {
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setLayout( null );

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel( "GENERAL SETTINGS:" );
        label1.setBounds( 10, 15, 150, 20 );
        panel3.add( label1 );

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel( "Tag Name:" );
        label2.setBounds( 10, 45, 300, 20 );
        panel3.add( label2 );

        JTextField jtext1 = new JTextField( "Tag xx123" );
        jtext1.setBounds(95, 45, 100, 20);
        panel3.add( jtext1 );

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel( "Description:" );
        label3.setBounds( 10, 65, 300, 20 );
        panel3.add( label3 );

        JTextField jtext2 = new JTextField( "Tag1" );
        jtext2.setBounds(95, 65, 100, 20);
        panel3.add( jtext2 );
    }
}
```

1. Main class should call the JTabbedPane (as separate) class;
2. JTabbedPane class should call createPageScreen1 (as separate) class;
3. JTabbedPane class should call createPageScreen2 (as separate) class;
4. JTabbedPane class should call createPageScreen3 (as separate) class;

Please show me directions, thanks!

Comment: But you actually said what to do... creat a class that wraps the JTabbedPane and the JPanels initialize the elements there and then obtain the intialized JTabbedPane and add it in the JFrame in the Main class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to encapsulate the methods that create panels by your custom classes extending some Swing commponent, e.g. `JPanel`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;

public class MainClass extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frmScms;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainClass window = new MainClass();
                    window.frmScms.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MainClass() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frmScms = new JFrame();
        frmScms.setTitle("SCMS");
        frmScms.setBounds(100, 100, 1080, 684);
        frmScms.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frmScms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmScms.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frmScms.setResizable(true);

        //Set the frame icon to an image loaded from a file.
        frmScms.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("images/company-logo.gif").getImage());

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(2, 20, 1900, 1080);

        //tool tip for screen-1 to 6
        String tooltip1 = "Screen-1";
        String tooltip2 = "Screen-2";
        String tooltip3 = "Screen-3";


        // Create a tabbed pane
        tabbedPane.addTab("Screen-1", null, new PageScreen1(), tooltip1);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Screen-2", null, new PageScreen2(), tooltip2);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Screen-3", null, new PageScreen3(), tooltip3);
        frmScms.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        //warning message before close using X 
        frmScms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frmScms.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to close the application?", "Please Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
class PageScreen1 extends JPanel {
    private PageScreen1() {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/Front1.png");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(image, JLabel.CENTER);
        label2.setBounds( 10, 55, 1600, 900 );
        add(label2);
    }
}
```

---

```
class PageScreen2 extends JPanel {
    private PageScreen2() {
        setLayout( null );
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel( "LOG:" );
        label1.setBounds( 10, 15, 150, 20 );
        add( label1 );

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel( "Well 1 PMW Pressure Sensor - Tag xx123" );
        label2.setBounds( 10, 45, 300, 20 );
        add( label2 );
    }
}
```

---

```
class PageScreen3 extends JPanel {

    private PageScreen3() {
        setLayout( null );
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel( "GENERAL SETTINGS:" );
        label1.setBounds( 10, 15, 150, 20 );
        add( label1 );

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel( "Tag Name:" );
        label2.setBounds( 10, 45, 300, 20 );
        add( label2 );

        JTextField jtext1 = new JTextField( "Tag xx123" );
        jtext1.setBounds(95, 45, 100, 20);
        add( jtext1 );

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel( "Description:" );
        label3.setBounds( 10, 65, 300, 20 );
        add( label3 );

        JTextField jtext2 = new JTextField( "Tag1" );
        jtext2.setBounds(95, 65, 100, 20);
        add( jtext2 );   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Crazyjavahacking, just to clarify, still do I have to keep all the separate classes in the same main Class file? If I want to keep (for ex;) PageScreen1 class in separate class file, how do I link to the main Class, thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to break your code into classes.  You move the code to create each JPanel of the JTabbedPane into its own class.

The MainClass:

```
package com.ggl.split;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class MainClass {

    private JFrame frmScms;

    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JPanel panel3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainClass window = new MainClass();
                    window.frmScms.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MainClass() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frmScms = new JFrame();
        frmScms.setTitle("SCMS");
        frmScms.setBounds(100, 100, 1080, 684);
        frmScms.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frmScms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmScms.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frmScms.setResizable(true);

        // Set the frame icon to an image loaded from a file.
        frmScms.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("images/company-logo.gif")
                .getImage());

        // creating pages
        panel1 = new Page1().getPanel1();
        panel2 = new Page2().getPanel2();
        panel3 = new Page3().getPanel3();

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(2, 20, 1900, 1080);

        // tool tip for screen-1 to 6
        String tooltip1 = "Screen-1";
        String tooltip2 = "Screen-2";
        String tooltip3 = "Screen-3";

        // Create a tabbed pane
        tabbedPane.addTab("Screen-1", null, panel1, tooltip1);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Screen-2", null, panel2, tooltip2);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Screen-3", null, panel3, tooltip3);
        frmScms.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        // warning message before close using X
        frmScms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frmScms.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                JFrame frame = (JFrame) e.getSource();
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                        "Are you sure you want to close the application?",
                        "Please Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The Page1 class:

```
package com.ggl.split;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Page1 {

    private JPanel panel1;

    public Page1() {
        createPageScreen1();
    }

    // function for panel - page - 1
    private void createPageScreen1() {
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/Front1.png");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(image, JLabel.CENTER);
        label2.setBounds(10, 55, 1600, 900);
        panel1.add(label2);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel1() {
        return panel1;
    }

}
```

The Page2 class:

```
package com.ggl.split;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Page2 {

    private JPanel panel2;

    public Page2() {
        createPageScreen2();
    }

    // function for panel - page - 2
    private void createPageScreen2() {
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(null);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("LOG:");
        label1.setBounds(10, 15, 150, 20);
        panel2.add(label1);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Well 1 PMW Pressure Sensor - Tag xx123");
        label2.setBounds(10, 45, 300, 20);
        panel2.add(label2);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel2() {
        return panel2;
    }

}
```

The Page3 class:

```
package com.ggl.split;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Page3 {

    private JPanel panel3;

    public Page3() {
        createPageScreen3();
    }

    // function for panel - page - 3
    private void createPageScreen3() {
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setLayout(null);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("GENERAL SETTINGS:");
        label1.setBounds(10, 15, 150, 20);
        panel3.add(label1);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Tag Name:");
        label2.setBounds(10, 45, 300, 20);
        panel3.add(label2);

        JTextField jtext1 = new JTextField("Tag xx123");
        jtext1.setBounds(95, 45, 100, 20);
        panel3.add(jtext1);

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Description:");
        label3.setBounds(10, 65, 300, 20);
        panel3.add(label3);

        JTextField jtext2 = new JTextField("Tag1");
        jtext2.setBounds(95, 65, 100, 20);
        panel3.add(jtext2);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel3() {
        return panel3;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gilbert Le Blanc, this is what exactly I wanted, Thank you so much for your time and help!